# Squeaky sounds from our GE dryer. Is this the dryer belt failing?

Tags: dryer, appliances, sounds

Our 6 year old GE dryer has a slight (so far) problem. Just as the drum start spinning it makes a squeaky sound. Then it goes away, but I can still hear a reduced version of the squeak every now and then as the drum turns. Seem like it gets worse with a full load. The squeak last less than a second and is not very load.. It has done this for while and it works just as great as it always has but I have a feeling the squeak is telling me something needs to be done and I do not want that to be all of a sudden leaving us stuck without a dryer. Our expensive Samsung dryer totally died on Dec 23 without any forewarning and will be very expensive to fix so we are back to the good 'ol GE which in many ways dries clothes better. I need to keep it alive though!

Answer (score 3):

Belt and/or rollers (that support the drum as it rotates). Commonly available as a kit of both, often for barely more money than either alone, and the major pain is getting in there to replace them, so just do both is my usual approach.

Comment: And be patient... there are usually a few brackets that have to be removed to replace the belt...+1

Answer (score 2):

If the GE dryer hasn't been used for a while, that could be a factor.  But quite a few times when faced with a squeaky dryer, my experience has been:

- cold room
- bearing "dry"  (many dryers have two of these at the bottom rear of the dryer, and a drop of oil will quickly quiet it, as well as warming up from use)
- front of drum slides, which are plastic bearings, which the front of the drum slides on
- other gaskets or seals
- belt and/or belt tensioner

I would check out the bearings first, if you can easily get to them.  Particularly in an older dryer.  They can be replaced, but oil usually buys allot of life.

Then I would look at plastic slides, which if worn, will need replacement.  Easy repair for a DIY.

But your best approach is to isolate the noise, if you can.  Worse when cold? Heavily loaded? And so on.

Finally, in my experience belts tend to fail with very heavy loads, and tend not to squeak unless the tension is not right on the belt.  Even if the belt, replacing them is usually within the capabilities of a DIYer.  In my experience the two rubber wheeled rollers need a drop of machine oil (sewing machine oil or even a tiny drop of engine oil, but WD-40 is not a lasting lubricant for this application). My vote is for the rear roller bearings.  If they get real bad, they are only $10 to $15 each, but they will run for a long time, and even longer with lube once a year or two.

Answer (score 1):

The squeaking noise is most likely the rear bearing of the drum or the front drum support. I just replaced both for a GE dryer which had been making a grinding noise. When I inspected the inside there was much wear on the front support. The cause was from over loading the dryer.

The repair was fairly-moderately easy. Here is the link for the front support kit that I used for my specific [GE model.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8O047W) Here's the link for the [rear bearing bushing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8O047W) I replaced.

You must remove the top of the dryer which than allows you to remove the front panel. This exposes the drum which is removed by unscrewing the fasteners inside the back drum wall. Once it's detached the rear bushing is replaced and the new front support can be installed.

When ordering parts always check that they are appropriate for your model. Also a second pair of hands is a good idea.